# How to add new rows to DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a way in spark to append a string in data frame and upload that data frame value in s3 in some txt file

i have build a DF by reading a text file from s3

```
val DF = spark.read.textFile("s3_path/file_name.txt")
DF.show(200,false)

    +----------------------------------+
    |value                             |
    +----------------------------------+
    |country:india                     |
    |address:xyz                       |
```

After this need to append and update some string in that file and upload it back to s3 in same location

expected output

```
+----------------------------------+
|value                             |
+----------------------------------+
|country:abcd                      |
|address:xyz                       |
|pin:1234                          |
```

Comment: Yes, It is possible. But you should think that working with Spark is not for updating a file row by row. Spark is for working with tons of data, in your case to update your df with millions of rows at the same time.

Comment: Thanks  @EmiCareOfCell44 for you response, I dont need to update row by row, it will only update that string which need to be update by user (depending upon user) and append.

Comment: Do you mean: 'Is there a way to add a column to a DF'?

Comment: not a column, but need to append a string to DF

Answer (score 0):

This is [union](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#union(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D) operation:

> Returns a new Dataset containing union of rows in this Dataset and another Dataset.